# forwarding call if callee/device is offline

Tags: asterisk, forwarding

I need to forward calls based on whether the end-device is turned on/off.
If the device is on, call the number normally, else forward it to the other members of the department.

```
exten => _[0-9]X,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}dev, 120) ;if phone is offline, execute line below
Dial(SIP/01dev&SIP/02dev&SIP/03dev, 16)
```

How can i determine whether or not a device is turned off?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948596/asterisk-how-check-if-a-number-is-busy-before-dialing-it

Answer (score 0):

A simple dialplan implantation for that can be checking the DIALSTATUS and using [ExecIf](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_ExecIf) - if didn't get an answer with 1st dial, do the 2nd dial:

```
exten => _[0-9]X,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}dev, 120) ;your 1st line
same => n,ExecIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" != "ANSWER"]?Dial(SIP/01dev&SIP/02dev&SIP/03dev, 16))
```

Note that 1st device can be "on" and dial will not return with ANSWER (BUSY, NOANSWER, CANCEL, etc.), but guess you want to make the 2nd dial even if device is "on" but did not answer.